# Flutterfire configure error 400 INVALID ARGUMENT

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have been trying to run flutterfire configure in my terminal for the firebase setup and it keeps returning.

```
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create ios helphub_trial (ios) --bundle-id=com.despositond.wixsite/my-site --json --project=helphubtrial 
ERROR: Failed to create iOS app for project helphubtrial. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

This is the youtube video I have been following I am at about 7:54:00  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPvVD8t02U8&t=28447s
[debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKpeF.png)
The debug log is the image I have attached. Been trying to find a solution and couldn't find anythine anywhere else. I am very new to coding and trying to get into app developement so if anyone can give me any guidence to solving this problem please do and thank you.

Was hoping for it to configure my project successfully for firebase.

Comment: The message ends with "See firebase-debug.log for more info" Did you do that?

Comment: Yup posted the debug log as an image and it’s kind of blended in with the YouTube url